# How can I expand my program to make it used on multiple devices and give them access to the old database without losing data?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I built a software for a farm using C#, the program was meant to keep track of the inventory and the financial exchanges related to the farms work.

The software was built to be installed on the manager's computer who then entered the farms data and retrieved reports and so. While the accountant used the same PC to use the financial part of the program with a different account.

Now the farm's business grew and more users need to use the system, can I move the database with the old data to a server so users can log in the system from different PC's at the time and continue the old tasks?

If I can - what do I change in my code?

P.S. the database was done in MS Access.

Comment: You have a whole lot of questions in there, and not much information. Obviously, you can migrate a database to a network share, and connect with it using a program. But I literally have no information about how you connect with the database, how the database is structured, and many more relevant things. Read into how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of information to go on here.  I can tell you that Access is a file based database system, and so whilst you could put the database files on a server or a NAS device with no problem with multiple users you should expect to run into the usual problems of Windows file sharing - VERY SLOW performance as a minimum.

It is also possible that the database may have been limited to a single user at a time, and without any more information impossible to know whether the developers have allowed for multi-user at all or whether you could have a situation where if several people do open the file at once one person may be overwriting another's data leading to corruption.

The short answer is that if the original developers are no longer around and you cannot ask the question of them then you probably need a new dedicated application to do the work which would mean either a complete rewrite or an alternative commercial application.

For multi-user Microsoft SQL Server, MySql, or even Firebird or another dedicated database back end would be the way to go.  The front end could be anything - Winforms, WPF, even a web application if that is what you want, but it would have to be written.

I hope that this is helpful.

Comment: Windows file shares, if done properly, can work pretty well with Access. Just don't put it on a $100 NAS and expect anything, you will need a decent server, but I've run multiple Access databases on network shares with almost no difference in performance than the same db running locally

Comment: multiple Access databases, agreed. However, multiple Users on a single Access database is in my experience likely to cause issues.  This is true of *any* file based database, pesumably because MS have assumed that everyone will use Client / Server now and have put no effort in maintaining or improving file sharing responsiveness for legacy products. Certainly, many such databases work better on older OSes...

Comment: I often have 4-5 users connecting to one database simultaneously through separate front-ends, less than the OP will have. In my experience, a share on a decent server will do fine for that. Obviously, if you want to scale to hundreds or thousands of users, you will have to ditch Access.

Comment: Hi Erik, your experience is clearly better than mine :-) Probably the hardware level that was causing the issue based on what you say...  If the OP wants to go that route, then without more information the best I can say is that he may not have to change anything other then the connection string for database in the new location to gain a connection.  Of course whether the code he has written has allowed for multi-user access I have no idea.  Opening multiple connections and leaving them permanently open whilst two people try to edit the same thing can lead to problems...